# How to consume standard routed API in a clean way?

Tags: c#, rest, api

Let's take an example of a generic API endpoint that looks as follows:

```
https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/{section}/{sort}/{window}/{showViral}/{page}
```

Conditions on this endpoint are as follows:

1. Arguments are optional. Default values will be used if not provided.
2. All the earlier arguments must be provided in order to use an argument. So in this example, if I were to get posts of page no 2, I must provide section, sort, window and showViral values.

I am trying to create a C# wrapper around such endpoints. My method looks somewhat as follows:

```
public static async Task<List<Image>> GetGallery(Section? section = null, Sort? sort = null, Window? window = null, bool? showViral = null, int? page = null)
{
    string uri = "gallery";
    if (section != null)
    {
        uri += "/" + section.ToString().ToLower();
        if(sort != null)
        {
            uri += "/" + sort.ToString().ToLower();
            if(window != null)
            {
                uri += "/" + window.ToString().ToLower();
                if (showViral != null)
                {
                    uri += "/" + showViral.ToString();
                    if (page != null)
                    {
                        uri += "/" + page;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JObject response = await NetworkHelper.ExecuteRequest(uri);
    return response["data"].ToObject<List<Image>>();
}
```

I'm not really happy with this implementation. This code looks very ugly. Any thoughts on how I can improve this?

Comment: Is this on topic here? Sounds like a job for Code Review SE.

Comment: @RubberDuck Not sure, but question seems inline with the other questions here. Anyhow, I'm not really asking for review. I'm asking for entirely different solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution using LINQ:

```
string CreatePath(params string[] segments)
{
    var includedSegments = segments.TakeWhile(segment => segment != null));
    return String.Join("/", includedSegments);
}
```

Then you just need to pass your string segment arguments in order, converted to string. Alternatively you could do the string conversion inside:

```
string CreatePath(params object[] segments)
{
    var includedSegments = segments.TakeWhile(segment => segment != null)).Select(segment => segment.ToString());
    return String.Join("/", includedSegments);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a fluent solution. It needs some interfaces, but the usage for a client is very simple and guided, since autocompletion will automatically suggest two possibilities at each point: Images or the subcriteria, e.g. Sort(...);

So for the client, the usage would be like this:

```
var g = // get gallerygetter from somewhere 

// get all images
var images = g.Get().Images;

// subsets
var images = g.Get().Section(section).Sort(sort).Images;

var images = g.Get()
    .Section(section)
    .Sort(sort)
    .Window(window)
    .ShowViral(showViral)
    .Page(page)
    .Images;
```

Now of course, in order to support such a nice use, you need some interfaces. But you can implement all those in a single class.

```
public interface IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViralPage : IGallery
{ 
    IGallery Page(int x);
}

public interface IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViral : IGallery
{
    IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViralPage ShowViral(bool x);
}

public interface IGallerySectionSortWindow : IGallery
{
    IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViral Window(Window w);
}

public interface IGallerySectionSort : IGallery
{
    IGallerySectionSortWindow Sort(Sort s);
}

public interface IGallerySection : IGallery
{
    IGallerySectionSort Section(Section s);
}

public IGallery
{
    Task<List<Image>> Images { get; }
}

public IGalleryGetter : IGallery
{
    IGallerySection Get();
}

public Gallery 
    : IGallery
    , IGalleryGetter
    , IGallerySection
    , IGallerySectionSort
    , IGallerySectionSortWindow
    , IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViral 
    , IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViralPage
{
    private string uri = "gallery";

    public Task<List<Image>> Images 
    {
        JObject response = await NetworkHelper.ExecuteRequest(uri);
        return response["data"].ToObject<List<Image>>();
    }

    public IGallerySection Get()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IGallerySectionSort Section(Section section)
    {
        uri += "/" + section.ToString().ToLower();
        return this;
    }

    public IGallerySectionSortWindow Sort(Sort sort)
    {
        uri += "/" + sort.ToString().ToLower();
        return this;
    }

    public IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViral Window(Window window)
    {
        uri += "/" + window.ToString().ToLower();
        return this;
    }

    public IGallerySectionSortWindowShowViralPage ShowViral(bool show_viral)
    {
        uri += "/" + show_viral.ToString().ToLower();
        return this;
    }

    public IGallery Page(int page)
    {
        uri += "/" + page.ToString().ToLower();
        return this;
    } 

}
```

Comment: This is *really* innovative. I hadn't thought about this. One problem that I see is the service could have many different endpoints for different things and I'll end up with so many interfaces. But seriously, great solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve this by separate the path joining method.

```
public static string BuildPath(params object[] paths) {
    string result = "";
    if (paths != null) {        
        foreach(var path in paths) {
            if (path == null) break;
            result += "/" + path;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then your implementation will make more sense, because it is one-liner

```
string uri = BuildPath("gallery", section, sort, window, showViral, page);
```

I did this in a fiddler here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/w9n0wg. Kindly noted that this is mimicking of your code behaviour, and does not do URL path encoding at all.